# Extracting proper nouns from stemmed text in java

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp, porter-stemmer

I am using OpenNLP for extracting proper nouns from a sentence. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import opennlp.tools.cmdline.parser.ParserTool;
import opennlp.tools.parser.Parse;
import opennlp.tools.parser.Parser;
import opennlp.tools.parser.ParserFactory;
import opennlp.tools.parser.ParserModel;

public class ParserTest {

    static Set<String> nounPhrases = new HashSet<>();

    private static String line = "iran india pai oil due euro delhi iran ask indian refin essar oil mangalor refineri petrochem mrpl clear oil due amount billion euro month lift sanction iran told indian author three year mechan pai cent oil import bill rupe keep remain cent pend payment channel clear end.";

    public void getNounPhrases(Parse p) {
        if (p.getType().equals("NNP") || p.getType().equals("NNPS")) {
             nounPhrases.add(p.getCoveredText());
             System.out.println(p.getCoveredText());
        }

        for (Parse child : p.getChildren()) {
             getNounPhrases(child);
        }
    }


    public void parserAction() throws Exception {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\asus\\Downloads\\en-parser-chunking.bin");
        ParserModel model = new ParserModel(is);
        Parser parser = ParserFactory.create(model);
        Parse topParses[] = ParserTool.parseLine(line, parser, 1);
        for (Parse p : topParses){
            //p.show();
            getNounPhrases(p);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new ParserTest().parserAction();
        System.out.println("List of Noun Parse : "+nounPhrases);
    }
}
```

The problem is its a stemmed text (I used Porter Stemming Algorithm) so every word is in lower case. Because of that the proper nouns are not getting extracted. Is my above approach of extracting proper nouns is correct? If yes, then what changes I have to make in the code to make it work? If no, then suggest me a new approach along with a sample code would help me do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i think unless you train a chunker model for noun phrases on the stemmed text, you will have to run the noun phrases extraction further upstream in your processing pipeline, before the stemming is done. Also, it appears to me based on your input string above, that in your process you are eliminating stop words as well as stemming, this will cause a problem as well, because you will not be able to properly align the two sets of spans downstream. 
So, if you have control over the process that feeds you the stemmed text, you should move noun phrases up stream, and have the raw tokens, stemmed tokens, NNPs, and any other metadata such as NER results passed down to where you are now...then you'd have something to work with.
HTH